# How does Wikipedia handle URL's such that "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP" is possible?

Tags: url

Notice the slash in "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP" How does it not misinterpret TCP as a subfolder?

Answer (score 7):

It has an .htaccess rule that spots the `/wiki/` and interprets everything after that as a parameter to be passed to a PHP script, a bit like this:

```
/pagedisplay.php?page=TCP%2FIP
```

Note that the slash gets converted to `%2F`.

This happens behind the scenes so you don't see the url being rewritten.